# Reading from a file directly through Python Shell

Tags: python

I am a newbie just learning how to code with python and seem to have hit a snag.

I am using Windows Powershell and am accessing the python shell through the python command launching shell within Powershell.

I am trying to read directly from a text file without calling on a script by using the `open('filename','r')`command but it appears I'm doing something wrong because everytime I do it only displays `<_io.TextIOWrapper name='ex15_sample.txt' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>`.

What should I be doing differently? Do I need to establish a variable? And how does one do so when accessing it through the shell directly, as it seems to have more limited options?

Answer (score 0):

The output you got means it works correctly because you just have opened the file not read it, to read the file you have to read it line by line.

Here's an example to read a text file in `Python` with the right approach:

1.: First write a python file as:

```
import sys

txtfile = sys.argv[1]
with open(txtfile) as f:
    content = f.readlines()
```

2.Then you can open a file in **PowerShell** as:

**PowerShell Command:**

```
PS> python evil_61.py evilwords.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Your output is just fine, you just have to assign the result of the `open` function to a variable, that is `file = open('filename','r')` and you read the file contents as follows

```
for line in file:
    print(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your answers! After doing more digging in to my code and reading the responses I discovered what I was doing wrong.

Within the Python Shell (using Powershell) I first established the text file as a variable

```
    txt = open(ex15_sample.txt)
```

after which I called on upon it using the read function

```
    print(txt.read())
```

Which then successfully printed the contents of the entire text document.